# Google Sheet Formula for Selecting specific rows

Tags: google-sheets-formula

Here I want to select the rows in which Column E is blank. Some of the rows which I want to select are shown in the [rows to be selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJ9ms.png)image.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a formula that just shows these empty rows you can use the [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) function.
This takes in 2 (3 if you count the optional) parameters, with 1 being the range of data, and 2 being your query.

In this case, your range would probably be `A1:E`, but I can't tell due to the size of your screenshot.

Now for the query I put the following together: `"select * where E = ''"`

Basically, what happens here is that the formula is going to go through every row and select all the data (`select *`) in that row where column E contains an empty string (`where E = ''`).

So if you're on the same sheet still, you can use the formula `=QUERY(A1:E, "select * where E = ''")`

If you want to use this formula on another sheet in the same document you'll have to replace the range.

Example: `=QUERY(Sheet1!A1:C9, "select * where C = ''")`

And if you want to use this formula on an entirely different document you can use the IMPORTRANGE formula to get the data. With this, you'll need to change the range and columns though.

example: `=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("sheetid", "Sheet1!A1:C"), "select * where Col5 = ''")`

(E changes into Col5 since it's the 5th letter in the alphabet)

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY(A:E; "where E is null")
```